# Doctrine - OneToOne relationship not working with extends MappedSuperclass

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mappedsuperclass

I try to use @MappedSuperclass. It works well for simple variable (int, string...) and OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship. But OneToOne relationship doesn't work.

I have two MappedSuperclass with OneToOne relationship :
_SiteUser

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass _SiteUser
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="_SiteModule\_Repository\_SiteUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="site_users")
 */
class _SiteUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Groups("id")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Groups({"username"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Groups({"password"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var _SiteUserTo
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="_SiteModule\_Entity\_SiteUserTo", mappedBy="user")
     * @Gedmo\Versioned()
     */
    protected $user_to;
```

_SiteUserTo

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass _SiteUserTo
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="_SiteModule\_Repository\_SiteUserToRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_to")
 */
class _SiteUserTo
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Groups("id")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var _SiteUser
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="_SiteModule\_Entity\_SiteUser", inversedBy="user_to")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

And this is my 2 class who extends these MappedSuperclass :
SiteUser

```
/**
 * SiteUser
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SiteModule\Repository\SiteUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="site_users")
*/
class SiteUser extends _SiteUser
{
}
```

SiteUserTo

```
/**
 * SiteUserTo
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SiteModule\Repository\SiteUserToRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_to")
*/
class SiteUserTo extends _SiteUserTo
{
}
```

When I generate entities from my MappedSuperclass (_SiteUser and _SiteUserTo), I got well a table named "users_to" with id and user_id. But when I generate entities from my others classes (SiteUser and SiteUserTo), it creates the table "users_to" with only id field. I don't know why...

If I update my SiteUser Class like this :

```
/**
 * Class SiteUser
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SiteModule\Repository\SiteUserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="site_users")
*/
class SiteUser extends _SiteUser
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $test;

    /**
     * @var SiteUserTo
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SiteModule\Entity\SiteUserTo", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $user_to;
}
```

And SiteUserTo like this :

```
/**
 * Class SiteUserTo
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SiteModule\Repository\SiteUserToRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_to")
*/
class SiteUserTo extends _SiteUserTo
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $test;

    /**
     * @var SiteUser
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SiteModule\Entity\SiteUser", inversedBy="user_to")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

I got the same problem, no field `user_id` in table `users_to`. But the field "test" is well created in the table `site_users` and in the table `users_to`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and
>   persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be
>   unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many
>   associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.
>   Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped
>   superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For
>   further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance
>   features have to be used.

Simply said you can not have @MappedSuperClass and @ORM\Entity annotations at the same time, hence the unexpected results

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html